# Segfault on linked list manipulation

Tags: c++, syntax, linked-list

I dont know why im getting this segfault here. I am trying to take every other node and place it in a new list.
Edit: this is what i ended up with but i still get a segfault

```
template <class T>
List<T> List<T>::mixSplit()
{
    List<T> newList;
    newList.length=0;
    for (int count=0;count<2;count++)
        newList.head=newList.head->next;
    newList.tail=tail;
    newList.head->prev=NULL;
    newList.tail->next=NULL;
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And remember to "check" (accept) the answers that best answer your own questions.

Comment: What is this for? `for (int count=0;count<1;count++)`

Comment: There's quite a few extra problems here, and the code doesn't at all do what you want it to do. That loop only ever runs once, for example, so it doesn't need to be there.

Comment: Im doing that to get every other node.

Answer (score 1):

On the first iteration of

```
for (int count=0;count<1;count++)
    newList.head=newList.head->next;
```

...`newList.head` is `NULL`...so using `newList.head->next` is a bad idea.

I'd recommend that you iterate over the current list fairly normally(i.e. `current = head; while(current) ...`), increment a counter within the loop to track the current position in the list, and whenever the loop counter is even or 0 (`counter % 2 == 0` or `(counter & 1) == 0`) use the standard 'list add' function on your new list to append a new node.